# Why does flex-direction: column and align-items: center; not position vertically?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, grid

I have a form that I want to move down using align-items:center property. This form is inside a parent wrapper div and has the id of left. As align items is used to position vertically, why does the left div stick to the top and not move down to the center?

To make it clear what I expect to happen, I have included an image
https://twitter.com/yama_code/status/1061751980400488449

The left div has the following properties

```
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:column;
        flex:1;
        align-items:center;
        height:100vh;
```

Comment: please include the enclosing HTML, and any other CSS that may affect the rendered result

Comment: In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows **all** of your **relevant** code and details any failed [**attempts made so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with clearly stating what your desired **result** is. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: https://twitter.com/yama_code/status/1061751980400488449

Comment: *"As align-items is used to position vertically..."* That was your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because `align-items` affects the child elements, or the elements within the flex container.

Try instead putting the element you wish to be centre-aligned inside of a parent with `#left`'s properties.